# Is there anyway to rotate only a part of an already made animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, mixamo

I need to modify an catwalk animation but I can't find anyway to do that..
Basically, I have this catwalk animation that the model mades a turn in to the beginning and I need to remove it, and make the model walks on a linear path. I already tried to change the hips curves graph, parenting to a null, exclude some keyframes, turn keyframes but everything that I try its unsuccessful. There is any easy way to this? Sorry for the question I'm newbie on blender
[image: this is the default animation]
[image: this is basically what I want but poorly made]

The first gif is the original animation and the second is a poorly made version of what I need to   (pareting an empty)

EDIT: link for the blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rxrbt3-P6XzDcAjRV_40xH8SpcJKIEFf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want the character to go straight ahead, maybe simply repeat the first walk cycle as much as needed?